# Bootstrap select shows doesn't replace orignal dropdown but add its own

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using [this](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) for select combo,After adding its css and Js files i got this result.
Here what i have tried so far.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.css"/>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker show-tick form-control">
  <option>pen</option>
  <option>pencil</option>
  <option selected>brush</option>
</select>
```

The output.

[image]

So can you please have a look at this why this is happening ?

Comment: Please post your code here

Comment: updated,please have a look @ParagJadhav

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `rel="stylesheet"` is missing in both of the `link` tags.

Add `rel="stylesheet"` to both `link` tags and it will work fine. Sample below.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker show-tick form-control">
  <option>pen</option>
  <option>pencil</option>
  <option selected>brush</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does jQuery version is  causing issues?

Comment: @KhiradBanu Updated my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

this is because the sequence of loading css file not correct. Combo css file must load after loding all other css files then the issue will resovled. If still not resolve then css classes or properties are overriding somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Add the script to initialize bootstrap select

```
$('select').selectpicker();
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a0mdk9qp/1/)** to play with. Notice the sequence of links in which they are loaded.

1. [Jquery 3.2.1](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js)
2. [bootstrap.min.js](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js)
3. [bootstrap-select.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.js)
4. [bootstrap.min.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css)
5. [bootstrap-select.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.css)

There might be a conflict with the Jquery version you're loading in your code.

```
<select class="selectpicker show-tick form-control">
  <option>pen</option>
  <option>pencil</option>
  <option selected>brush</option>
</select>
```